# Failed to start SnappyData Server: Attempt to connect to distributed system timed out

Tags: snappydata

I'm trying to setup a SnappyData cluster on multiple nodes with 1 locator, 1 lead and 3 data servers.

Cluster configuration:
conf/locators:

```
snappydata1 -peer-discovery-port=10334 -dir=/opt/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/work/locator -heap-size=8192m
```

conf/leads:

```
snappydata1 -dir=/opt/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/work/lead -heap-size=8192m -member-timeout=12000
```

conf/servers:

```
snappydata2 -dir=/opt/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/work/server -heap-size=24g -locators=snappydata1:10334
snappydata3 -dir=/opt/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/work/server -heap-size=24g -locators=snappydata1:10334
```

I am starting the cluster using `./sbin/snappy-start-all.sh`.
Locator and lead starts successfully because its on same node(snappydata1) but data servers fail to start with below error:

```
> ./sbin/snappy-start-all.sh
 Logs generated in /opt/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/work/locator/snappylocator.log
 SnappyData Locator pid: 3067 status: running
   Distributed system now has 1 members.
   Started Thrift locator (Compact Protocol) on: snappydata1/X.X.X.251[1527]
 Logs generated in /opt/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/work/server/snappyserver.log
 Logs generated in /opt/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/work/server/snappyserver.log
 SnappyData Server pid: 24592 status: stopped
 Error starting server process:
 SystemConnectException: Attempt to connect to distributed system timed out - See log file for details.
 SnappyData Server pid: 13398 status: stopped
 Error starting server process:
 SystemConnectException: Attempt to connect to distributed system timed out - See log file for details.
 Logs generated in /opt/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/work/lead/snappyleader.log
 SnappyData Leader pid: 4382 status: running
   Distributed system now has 2 members.
   Starting job server on: 0.0.0.0[8090]
```

snappyserver.log:

```
19/03/25 08:07:12.076 UTC serverConnector<tid=0x17> INFO snappystore: GemFire P2P Listener started on  tcp:///X.X.X.207:4867
19/03/25 08:07:12.181 UTC PingSender<tid=0x2c> INFO snappystore: locator X.X.X.251(null)<v0>:10334 member address is X.X.X.251(3067:locator)<ec><v0>:37063
19/03/25 08:07:12.181 UTC PingSender<tid=0x2c> INFO snappystore: Locator has disabled floating membership coordination
19/03/25 08:07:12.182 UTC serverConnector<tid=0x17> INFO snappystore: Attempting to join distributed system whose membership coordinator is X.X.X.251(3067:locator)<ec><v0>:37063 using membership ID X.X.X.207(24592):42456
19/03/25 08:08:13.188 UTC PingSender<tid=0x2e> INFO snappystore: locator X.X.X.251(null)<v0>:10334 member address is X.X.X.251(3067:locator)<ec><v0>:37063
19/03/25 08:08:17.193 UTC PingSender<tid=0x30> INFO snappystore: locator X.X.X.251(null)<v0>:10334 member address is X.X.X.251(3067:locator)<ec><v0>:37063
19/03/25 08:08:21.196 UTC PingSender<tid=0x32> INFO snappystore: locator X.X.X.251(null)<v0>:10334 member address is X.X.X.251(3067:locator)<ec><v0>:37063
19/03/25 08:08:25.201 UTC PingSender<tid=0x34> INFO snappystore: locator X.X.X.251(null)<v0>:10334 member address is X.X.X.251(3067:locator)<ec><v0>:37063
19/03/25 08:08:29.205 UTC PingSender<tid=0x36> INFO snappystore: locator X.X.X.251(null)<v0>:10334 member address is X.X.X.251(3067:locator)<ec><v0>:37063
```

All instances are able to do passwordless SSH and also port 80, 5050, 10334, 1527-30 are opened for all.

Please let me know if anything is wrong or missing in the configuration.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to setup cluster successfully after opening certain ports in AWS security group.
I followed [AWS Scripts to setup SnappyData](http://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/install/setting_up_cluster_on_amazon_web_services/#EC2) and observed that it needs more ports to be opened in security group for heartbeat etc.